# Dropdown wont toggle in bootstrap

Tags: html

Im trying to get my dropdown menu working but it wont toggle. The rest of the Navbar is working correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Zedex</title>
      <!-- needed scripts for bootstrap -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/js/jarallax.js"></script>
      <script src="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/js/jarallax-video.js"></script>
      <script>
         new WOW().init();
      </script> 
      <!-- Extern scripts saved in the root folder -->  
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Test</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="view hm-white-light jarallax" data-jarallax='{"speed": 0.1}' data-jarallax-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAcC2TpcGA0">
         <div class="full-bg-img">
            <div class="container flex-center">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
                     <div class="text-center">
                        <h1 class="display-2 mb-2 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s" align="center" style="font-size:100pt;">Zedex</h1>
                        <h5 class="font-up mb-3 mt-1 font-bold wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s" style="font-size:30pt;">We live. We love. We Game.</h5>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Im new to all this html and Bootstrap stuff. I researched but i cant find anything that could help me. I hope you can help me i dont know what to do else.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Try the process of elimination and remove most of your scripts. We need a [mcve] with an emphasis on minimal

Comment: Im an idiot. One of the links was duplicated and caused the problem.